# Css/PHP Adjust image width then trim top and bottom to fit

Tags: php, css

I have images in a database that are dynamically loaded, these images are all different sizes but I would like to adjust them in a unique way.

[Please see this example.](http://www.mycityvenue.co.uk/image.jpg)

I would like the images to fit the width and then trip the remainder on the top and bottom, then on top of that, make the whole thing responsive.

Comment: 1. That URL leads to a `403 Forbidden` 2. What have you tried?

Comment: This is the correct url

www.mycityvenue.co.uk/image.jpg

Comment: Specified Url is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what you need but without seeing existing code I can't help you to generate an actual solution.

Essentially when each image is generated you should first wrap it in a div.

Then, depending on the size of the images and how many you can fit within whatever width you want at desktop, let's say that's 1140px.  Give the div's you just generated a class of image-box, then style that box to be the size you want.  Let's say you want 4 boxes across width wise with a margin of 3.8%.

Now just calculate all your widths to find the width of your boxes...  You would have 3 margin gaps between 4 boxes, so thats 3.8% * 3 = 11.4% then... 100% - 11.4% = 88.6%

That means we have 88.6% width to split between our 4 boxes... 88.6% / 4 = 22.15%

So, we give the boxes a width of 22.15% and a margin-right of 3.8%

You'll have to either generate a class dynamically on every 4th box, or use something like `:nth-child()` to tell every 4th box to have `margin-right: 0;`

Of course these boxes will be float: left etc to make the responsive functionality, and all boxes will have to be in a container.

We'll use media queries to make the boxes only 2 boxes wide or just 1 long column of boxes.

As for trimming the image itself, once the box is made and has a set size (height in px), just define `overflow: hidden;` on the image-box container to hide what's left.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Let me know if you need any assistance with code.  Just edit your post above and comment. =)